# How to configure schedules to run pipelines on two different agents on Azure?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have created "Test dev" pipeline on Azure and there are two agents configured "XC1" and "XC2".

I want to XC1 and XC2 agents should run on "Test dev" pipeline at different timings(4 PM and 6 PM)

*Here is the yaml code*

```
initial.yml

trigger:
- none

# Setting Timer

schedules:
- cron: 16 * * 1-6
  displayName: Regression Run
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  always: true
  
 
 # Parameters for UI and default Parameters

parameters:
- name: agents
  displayName: Agent
  type: string
  default: TT1
  values:
  - TT1
  - TT2
- name: tests
  displayName: "Testing agents"
  type: string
  
  
stages:
- template: core.yml
  parameters:
    agents: ${{ parameters.agents }}
    tests: ${{ parameters.tests }}


core.yml

- stage: testagent
  displayName: Middaytest
  
  variables:
    - group: Credentials
    - name: 'AGENT'
      value: ${{ parameters.agents }}
    - name: 'TEST_SEQUENCE'
      value: ${{ parameters.tests }}
    

  jobs:
  - job: testagent
    displayName: Middaytest
    timeoutInMinutes: 400
    pool:

      name: nightlytest
      demands:
      - agent.name -equals $(AGENT)
    steps: #empty
```

Currently schedule is working properly on "XC1" agent but how to configure for "XC2" agent.

Please help me.

Comment: Hi Did you get a time to check out below steps and scripts. Did it work with you?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT It's working but I need to configure cron as mentioned in question. I want to run XC2 agent on "Test dev" pipleine. BY default it's running on "XC1" agent and it's should be like that but now I want to pass a XC2 agent as value and execute that agent on particular time as I mentioned like cron schedules.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT If you have any idea about this please help .

Comment: You can try moving  the `AgentStage` stage with the scheduled trigger to a separate pipeline. And add a powershell task to trigger the main pipeline via rest api. You can then pass the XC2 agent in the request body. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922636/can-you-pass-a-file-to-an-azure-pipeline) for more informatin. In this way, you can keep your original main yaml pipeline without using dependency and output variables.

Comment: Can you help me with modification. I'm new to this and getting bit hands here so. Thanks

Comment: See below update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional stage to set the agent variable according to the time it gets triggered. And add [dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-dependencies) on this stage for the following stages: See below detailed steps and yaml example:

1, Add an additional stage(ie. `AgentStage`) as the top stage.

2, Add a job(ie. `AgentJob`) in the `AgentStage` stage and run below script to set the agent Variable. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) for more information about Set a multi-job output variable.

```
stages:
- stage: AgentStage
  jobs:
  - job: AgentJob
    pool: 
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        $Time = Get-Date
        $hour = $Time.ToUniversalTime().Hour #convert scheduled time to the UTC time.

        #noted the time here is UTC time, please change the time value accordingly
        if($hour -eq 4){
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Agent;isOutput=true]agent1"
        }
        if($hour -eq 6){
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Agent;isOutput=true]agent2"
        }
      name: AgentTask
```

3, Add dependency for the following stages. And refer the output Variable using below format. (Noted: No need to define the `agents` in the parameters section.)

`stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`.

```
- template: core.yml
  parameters:
    agents: $[stageDependencies.AgentStage.AgentJob.outputs['AgentTask.Agent']]
    tests: ${{ parameters.tests }}
```

---

```
 variables:
    - group: Credentials
    - name: 'AGENT'
      value: $[stageDependencies.AgentStage.AgentJob.outputs['AgentTask.Agent']]
    - name: 'TEST_SEQUENCE'
      value: ${{ parameters.tests }}
```

See below full yaml example:

```
parameters:
- name: tests
  displayName: "Testing agents"
  type: string

stages:
- stage: AgentStage
  jobs:
  - job: AgentJob
    pool: 
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        $Time = Get-Date
        $hour = $Time.ToUniversalTime().Hour #convert scheduled time to the UTC time.

        #noted the time here is UTC time, please change the time value accordingly 
        if($hour -eq 4){
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Agent;isOutput=true]agent1"
        }
        if($hour -eq 6){
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Agent;isOutput=true]agent2"
        }
      name: AgentTask
    

- template: core.yml
  parameters:
    agents: $[stageDependencies.AgentStage.AgentJob.outputs['AgentTask.Agent']]
    tests: ${{ parameters.tests }}


- stage: testagent
  
  # dependsOn AgentStage stage

  dependsOn: AgentStage
  displayName: Middaytest
  
  variables:
    - group: Credentials
    - name: 'AGENT'
      value: $[stageDependencies.AgentStage.AgentJob.outputs['AgentTask.Agent']]
    - name: 'TEST_SEQUENCE'
      value: ${{ parameters.tests }}
    

  jobs:
  - job: testagent
    displayName: Middaytest
    timeoutInMinutes: 400
    pool:

    name: nightlytest
    demands:
    - agent.name -equals $(AGENT)
    steps: #empty
```

The stage in template core.yml should be added dependsOn `AgentStage` stage too

```
# core.yml

parameters:
  agents: ""
  tests: ""

stages:
- stage:
  dependsOn: AgentStage
  variables: 
    agent: ${{parameters.agents}}
```

Update:

You can create a separate pipeline and trigger the main pipeline according to the scheduled time via [rest api](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/%7BpipelineId%7D/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1). See below example:

1, Triggerring pipeline:

```
  trigger:
- none

# Setting Timer

schedules:
- cron: 16 * * 1-6
  displayName: Regression Run
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  always: true

 pool: 
   vmImage: windows-latest
 steps:
 - powershell: |
         $Time = Get-Date
         $hour = $Time.ToUniversalTime().Hour #convert scheduled time to the UTC time.

         #noted the time here is UTC time, please change the time value accordingly 
         $body=""
    
         if($hour -eq 4){  
            
                $body= '{
                         "templateParameters":{
                             "agents": "XC1"
                           }
                        }'
          }


         if($hour -eq 6){
             $body= '{
                         "templateParameters":{
                             "agents": "XC2"
                           }
                        }'
            }
         $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
         Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $trurl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

So when this triggering pipeline gets triggered on the scheduled timing. It triggers your main pipeline via rest api. And the parameters `agents` in the mail pipeline will be overrode by the agents you defined in the request body.

Comment: Thanks @Levi, How to implement this solution to UI defined pipeline? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740364/how-to-run-scheduled-azure-devops-pipeline-with-two-different-agents-pools