# How to run scheduled Azure DevOps pipeline with two different agents pools

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have `Azure DevOps` `pipeline` and I want to run it nightly run with two different `agent pool`, one `dev` and one `prod`.

This is the `pipeline` with default `dev` `agent pool`:

[image: dev]

In the schedule setting there is no option to set different `agent pool` to the runs:

[image: schedule]

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649197/how-to-configure-schedules-to-run-pipelines-on-two-different-agents-on-azure) (solution with `yaml` settings), but I didn't found a way to use it in my `pipeline` (my pipeline defined in `Azure DevOps` `UI` settings).

Comment: You can't run a pipeline job on the same stage for separate agents. You can do different agent jobs within the same stage, but not the same jobs. You'll need to create a separate stage.

Comment: You could create a copy of the pipeline with a new schedule and a different agent pool

Comment: Tanks @GeralexGR, this is my current simple solution, I don't like it because it forced me to maintenance two pipelines instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use GUI classic pipelines you could define two different jobs that will run on different agent pools. This way you could have a single pipeline that you will run depending on your schedule.

[image]

When using YAML syntax you could define different stages to accomplish the same result.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Stage`. The first stage's job will use one pool and the second stage will use a different pool. They can then be scheduled or triggered independently. You can also clone the first stage to save you the time of duplicating the tasks.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)

Comment: Thanks @joe, but looks like your solution is relevant to release pipeline.

Comment: @lior.i you can also have stages on your build pipelines. The problem is that you cannot have different schedules for those stages and you should have the same.

Comment: @GeralexGR, I have no problem with them be in the same time. I didn't saw a way to add stages to my build pipeline, just in the release pipeline.

Comment: @lior.i do you have GUI pipelines for build or YAML ones? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: @GeralexGR, I'm using UI pipelines, the link that you attached explains the release pipeline: ```You can organize the deployment jobs in your release pipeline into stages.```

Comment: @lior.i The link that I attached is for build pipelines. Release pipelines are only supported on GUI. When you see YAML syntax is refereed to build pipelines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243614/discussion-between-lior-i-and-geralexgr).